# How to revert indent-tabs-mode when editing makefiles in emacs?

Tags: emacs, makefile

I've got the following in my `.emacs` since for most source code I use spaces only:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
      (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)))
```

This messes up my makefiles though since they require tabs. How do I work around this so that I get spaces by default for all source code, but makefiles retain tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add an add-hook for makefile-mode to change it back.

```
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
      (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```